# Fastest way to perform multiple "IN" queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly horrible query using 2 "IN" statements that needs running on our database.  Firstly the schema (Simplified for this example):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SystemUser]
(
    [SystemUserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicationUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SystemUserID] ASC
    )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group]
(
    [GroupID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [GroupID] ASC
    )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupMembership]
(
    [SystemUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupMembership] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SystemUserID] ASC,
        [GroupID] ASC
    )
)
GO
```

What I want to do is find all "SystemUser" records that match a list of SystemUserIDs that do NOT have membership to a "Group" that is in a list of GroupIDs.

So 2 seperate lists of IDs beng compared in one query.  The fastest way I can think of doing this currently is below:

```
SELECT SU.SystemUserID
FROM [dbo].[SystemUser] SU 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT GM.SystemUserID
    FROM [dbo].[GroupMembership] GM
    WHERE GM.GroupID IN
    (
        1, 7, 8, 10, 32
    )
) GM ON GM.SystemUserID = SU.SystemUserID
WHERE SU.SystemUserID IN
(
    10, 61, 80, 93, 98
)
AND GM.SystemUserID IS NULL /* Not matched */
```

Is there anything I'm missing; would a "WHERE NOT EXISTS" check be more efficient?  Or can you think of a better way of processing and filtering by the two lists?

Comment: Do you only need SystemUserID from SystemUser or is it only for a sample purpose here?

Comment: I only need the id brought back;  in context this query is being used to filter a list of SystemUserIDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or later,

```
SELECT SU.SystemUserID
FROM [dbo].[SystemUser] SU 
WHERE SU.SystemUserID IN
(
    10, 61, 80, 93, 98
)
EXCEPT
SELECT GM.SystemUserID
FROM [dbo].[GroupMembership] GM
WHERE GM.GroupID IN
(
    1, 7, 8, 10, 32
)
```

Comment: I like the syntax; definitely one to keep an eye on. Running with the execution plan; with 14 ids in both lists the query cost of the `EXCEPT` version is 49% whilst the original version is 51%; so it does provide a minor performance improvement

Comment: Fair enough @SQLkiwi I'll have a look at the client statistics instead.

Comment: I went for this method; apart from the improved performance it is also much nicer syntaxically and easier to convert to LinqToSql in C# (Translating to `users.Except(userGroupMemberships)`) Cheers @AakashM

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `IN` (which emits separate queries), use `BETWEEN` to enclose ranges:

```
SELECT SU.SystemUserID 
FROM [dbo].[SystemUser] SU  
LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT GM.SystemUserID 
    FROM [dbo].[GroupMembership] GM 
    WHERE GM.GroupID BETWEEN 1 AND 5

) GM ON GM.SystemUserID = SU.SystemUserID 
WHERE SU.SystemUserID BETWEEN 10 AND 14
AND GM.SystemUserID IS NULL /* Not matched */
```

If your ranges are not at all sequential, create a temp table (or CTE), populate with values and then inner join to it.

Comment: Ah sorry Mitch; I didn't mention the integer lists may not be sequential (I'll update the example) though great point in the context.

Comment: Interesting point; like it!  Ok so multiple `BETWEEN` statements would be more efficient than an `IN` query?  Even in if the list of integers gets to around 100 items?

Answer (score 2):

Few problem queries can be solved by rewriting the text of the query, and yours is no exception. The culprit of performance problems almost always is missing indexes, and again yours is no exception.

```
SELECT SU.SystemUserID
FROM [dbo].[SystemUser] SU 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT GM.SystemUserID
    FROM [dbo].[GroupMembership] GM
    WHERE GM.GroupID IN
    (
        1, 7, 8, 10, 32
    )
) GM ON GM.SystemUserID = SU.SystemUserID
WHERE SU.SystemUserID IN
(
    10, 61, 80, 93, 98
)
AND GM.SystemUserID IS NULL /* Not matched */
```

So you need:

1. `GroupID` index on `GroupMembership`
2. `SystemUserID` index on `SystemUser`
3. `SystemUserID` index on `GroupMembership` (for the join)

You DDL (that's for adding it!) reveals that you have solved 2) and 3), but not 1). So add the missing index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_GroupMembership_GroupID ON GroupMembership(GroupID, SystemUserID)
```

As a rule of thumb: many-to-many tables of the form (leftId, rightId) **always** need both an index on `(leftId, rightId)` and one on `(rightId, leftId)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I have more often got better results from joining to a temp table with the desired values in it rather than using IN when the value list increases. with 100 values, I'd got that way first by habit but would probably write up both and compare plans and statistics before it goes live.